# Most efficient way of writing a list (of lists of lists) to a csv in Python?

Tags: python, list, file, python-2.7, file-io

Given (pseudocode):

```
for city in cities:
  for info in city:
      #add some stuff to a list
   #add each list to a list (creating a list of lists)

  with open('file.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
      writer.writerows(the list of lists) #in order of list
```

So I'm opening the file for **each city** and appending each list of each
list-of-lists. What's a more efficient (quicker) way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you want to use the list again from python or just storing for output

Comment: Good question. No, once I write to the csv, I no longer need the lists. (this goes for each list in the list-of-lists-of-lists).

Comment: use csvwriter module for writing into csv file and can you provide the list of list example

Comment: example updated to show that I'm already using *csv.writer*

Comment: I already think this write is the most efficient one what problem are you facing or instead of writing each time you can write it one time

Comment: Why don't you just do the open once right at the top? Then format each list of lists to be written to the csv and write them.

Comment: Do you want it memory-efficient or CPU-efficient? Also, have you profiled this code and located the bottlenecks? Odds are that the slowest operation there is the IO, which is little you can do about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I'm missing the point, but isn't it just a simple rearrangement to simply open the file once and then write at the end of every city loop?

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for city in cities:
        for info in city:
            #add some stuff to a list
        #add each list to a list (creating a list of lists)

    writer.writerows(the list of lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to "human" read the file you could use the pickle module and simply dump the 2d list to file. Your program can then read the data back in at a later date and the data structure will be in tact.

Comment: Or, if the data is completely textual, the JSON module. More portable and safe than pickle.

Comment: I should have specified *csv* rather than *file* in the title, to indicate that yes, the file needs to be human-readable. Title updated.

Comment: `pickle` is something to be avoided, not embraced.